# Keying into external variable with Mongodb field in aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is it possible to use a document field to key into an external object in a MongoDB update using aggregation pipeline?

Here's the idea with an object that has a single key, my actual use case will be an updateMany with an object with many ObjectIds as keys. Imagine there's a MongoDB doc with an _id of '123456':

```
const fooBarId = '123456'
const someObj = {}
someObj[fooBarId] = 'fooBar'

mongoApi.update(
   { _id: ObjectId(fooBarId) },
   [{ $set: { someField: someObj['$_id'] } }]
)
```

Currently, I see `null` as the value in the updated document when I'm testing this. I should see `fooBar`. If I can get this update working with one document, then I can apply the same logic to an updateMany where `someObj` has many keys of ObjectIds with values that I'd like to set the new field to individually for each.

Comment: If you know the filter criteria: `{ _id: ObjectId(fooBarId) },`. Why not use it on the update `{ $set: { someField: someObj.fooBarId  } }`?

Comment: Didn't work, I don't think the `$` will reference doc variables outside of a mongodb aggregation. I'm trying to use update with aggregation pipeline

Comment: This is a contrived example, I'm doing an updateMany with a `someObj` that has many ObjectIds as keys. I want to set the new field to value of `someObj` key based on the ObjectId.

Comment: I don't think it is possible this way. The common practice in this case is to use a `bulkUpdate`. another option is to use a more complicated query. but `bulkUpdate` seems the best way to go

Comment: Would this not be possible in a regular non-update aggregation? Can you not key into objects with doc fields in an aggregation like I'm doing here? Do I need to cast someObj to an aggregation variable first? I haven't tried that yet

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `$objectToArray`:

```
const someObj = {
                    "649d0bae47fa0b4db69f2cf6": 1,
                    "649d0bae47fa0b4db69f2cf8": 2
                };
db.collection.updateMany(
{$expr: {$in: [{$toString: "$_id"}, Object.keys(someObj)]}},
[
  {$set: {
      someField: {$getField: {
          input: {$first: {$filter: {
                input: {$objectToArray: someObj},
                cond: {$eq: ["$$this.k", {$toString: "$_id"}]}
          }}},
          field: "v"
      }}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fYWM0OAV9Y4)

Another option is to use `bulkUpdate` for such cases.

**EDIT:**
For mongodb versions older than 5.0, you can use [this:](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ymAJYTMurhg)

```
const someObj = {
                    "649d0bae47fa0b4db69f2cf6": 1,
                    "649d0bae47fa0b4db69f2cf8": 2
                };
db.collection.updateMany(
{$expr: {$in: [{$toString: "$_id"}, Object.keys(someObj)]}},
[
  {$set: {someField: {
        $first: {$reduce: {
            input: {$objectToArray: someObj},
            initialValue: [],
            in: {$concatArrays: [
                "$$value",
                {$cond: [
                    {$eq: ["$$this.k", {$toString: "$_id"}]},
                    ["$$this.v"],
                    []
                ]}
            ]}
        }}
  }}}
])
```

Comment: Can an external variable be set and passed to `$objectToArray`? I'm looking into if I can use a `$let` within a `$set` now but I'm not sure yet...

Comment: One moment let me try it out

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on an older version than version 5: MongoError: Invalid $set :: caused by :: Unrecognized expression '$getField' :( any equivalent expression for older versions? I think I'm 4.2

Comment: Updated the answer to support older versions

Comment: Upvoted since is a technically correct answer and helped lead me to the answer I'd like to go with in this case. Thanks.

Comment: Or perhaps even this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aDYHF3n2WXN).  I'm not sure (didn't test) if both would use an index, or not.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going with this:

```
const fooBarId = '123456'
const someObj = {}
someObj[fooBarId] = 'fooBar'

mongoApi.update(
        { _id: ObjectId(fooBarId) },
        [
            {
                $set: {
                    someField: {
                        $let: {
                            vars: { id: { $toString: "$_id" }, extObj: someObj },
                            in: {
                                $function: {
                                    body: `function(_id, obj) { return obj[_id] }`,
                                    args: [ "$$id", "$$extObj" ],
                                    lang: "js"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    )
```

Needed aggregation to be performant since someObj could theoretically be 5000 keys in length. This solution will work with an updateMany with a key of arbtirary length while maintaining a lookup time of O(1) for values in someObj.